# Loading Arabic Value from JSP to Mysql database

Tags: jsp, servlets

Added following line in JSP

```
page pageEncoding="utf-8" 
meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8
```

"

Added the following in Servlet class file

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

when i read the value in javascript i was able to get arabic content but when it comes to servlet the value i am getting is **Ø§Ù?ØªØ­Ø¯Ù?Ø« Ø¨Ù?Ø¬Ø§Ø­**

How to fix ?

Comment: If you read the Servlet-value in Eclipse debug, are you setting the correct encoding in IDE?  ''Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text File Encoding to UTF-8''

Comment: Even after doing that same problem Also Ø§Ù?ØªØ­Ø¯Ù?Ø« Ø¨Ù?Ø¬Ø§Ø­ stored in database . any solution for this ?